# How to display DialogFragment in ListFragment when onListItemClick fired

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentTabHost in a fragment and there I created a ListFragment Tab in FragmentTabHost that works fine.

I need to show a DialogFragment when I select an item from ListFragment Tab but it does not work.

It calls follow method when onlisttemclick fired

```
private void showEditDialog() {
       FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
            ChequeDetailsDialogFragment editNameDialog = new ChequeDetailsDialogFragment();
            editNameDialog.show(fm, "mydialog");
        }
```

It throws an exception & app stopped. LogCat is below.

```
D/AndroidRuntime(4388): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(4388): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(4388): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at com.example.touchpoint.CheckListFragmentTab.onListItemClick(CheckListFragmentTab.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process(4388): Sending signal. PID: 4388 SIG: 9
```

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: post the logcat and some more relevant code

Comment: this is a screen shot. extract the exeption part and post it as text in your post. there is a NullPointerException @ line 86 `CheckListFragmentTab.java`

Comment: But the works when I put showEditDialog() method in onCreateView instead of onListItemClick.

Comment: Could u please help me by giving some code that displays a DialogFragment on onListItemClick event in ListFragment Tab in under FragmentTabHost.

Comment: post your onListItemClick event code and also line 86 CheckListFragmentTab.java

Comment: @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  showEditDialog();

 }

Comment: Exact at which line you got NPE?